# Understanding the weakening rule

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I understand the weakening rule is a combination of two simpler rules: “precondition strengthening” and “postcondition weakening”.

Suppose $P$ is some unknown piece of code such that the following Hoare triple is partially correct. (All variables in the state vector $(x, y, u, v)$ are of integer type.)
$$\{x < y\} \; P \; \{u < v\}$$

How can I decide which of the following Hoare triples are partially correct? (Giving a counterexample if they are not)

a) $\{x < y\} \; P \; \{u \le v\} $

b) $\{x \leq y\} \; P \; \{u < v\} $

c) $\{x \leq y - 2\} \; P \; \{u < v\} $

---

My Attempt:

a) is partially correct as $\{x < y\} \; P \; \{u < v\} \therefore \{x < y\} \; P \; \{u \le v\} $ as $ \{u \le v\}$ is a weakened post condition.

b) is not partially correct counterexample x = y

c) is partially correct as if P $\{x < y\} \; P \; \{u < v\} \therefore  \{x \leq y - 2\} \; P \; \{u < v\} $ as $ \{x \leq y - 2\}$ is a strengthed pre condition.

Comment: In a nutshell, “precondition strengthening” means to "add" an "and" ($\land$) condition while “postcondition weakening” means to add an "or ($\lor$) condition.

Comment: The reason is simple; if $A$ implies $P$, then also $A \land B$ implies $P$, for $B$ wahtever. ANd if $P$ implies $B$, then $P$ implies $B \lor A$ for $A$ whatever.

Comment: Example: $x \le y$ is $x< y \lor x=y$ (with "or"). Thus $x \le y$ is a "weakening" of $x < y$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA does that mean $x ≤ y - 2 ∨ x = y - 2$ Is also a "weakening" of $x < 2$ and therefore c) should also be not partially correct?

Comment: No, it is a "strengthening” because $x \le y-2$ implies $x < y$ ($y-2 < y$).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thanks :)

Comment: The answers seem correct as written, you should be more explicit with (b) though.  What is an example of a $P$ in which the original claim holds, but the (b) claim fails?